# How to connect to local apache server from android on different network?(port forwarding)

Tags: android, apache, xampp, localhost, portforwarding

Let me tell you what I have done so far.
I am making an Android game app, and in the process of saving records and posting them to my local host server (and to my MySQL database), I ran into a problem.
I can access my local host from Android, when it is on the same wifi network.

However, I can't connect to the local host , when I use 4G with Android. 
My local `IPv4` address is `192.168.219.187`, and I tried port forwarding as suggested by other posts, with the 
following information:

```
Service ports:  8080 - 8080
Protocol Type: TCP
Internal Ip Address: 192.168.219.187
```

Any idea on how to connect to the local host, from devices on different networks?

Answer (score 0):

I was making a stupid mistake..  The default port my apache server used was not 8080, but instead 80.... I just changed my portforwarding from 8080 to 80 and then it worked!